# Generate date column within a range for every unique ID in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set which has unique IDs and names.

```
| ID       | NAME           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Jane           |
| 2        | Max            |
| 3        | Tom            |
| 4        | Beth           |
```

Now, i want to generate a column with dates using a date range for all the IDs. For example if the date range is ('2019-02-11', '2019-02-15') i want the following output.

```
| ID       | NAME           | DATE           |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 1        | Jane           | 2019-02-11     |
| 1        | Jane           | 2019-02-12     |
| 1        | Jane           | 2019-02-13     |
| 1        | Jane           | 2019-02-14     |
| 1        | Jane           | 2019-02-15     |
| 2        | Max            | 2019-02-11     |
| 2        | Max            | 2019-02-12     |
| 2        | Max            | 2019-02-13     |
| 2        | Max            | 2019-02-14     |
| 2        | Max            | 2019-02-15     |
```

and so on for all the ids. What is the most efficient way to get this in python?

Comment: cross merge with a calendar df with your dates? what did you try?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a pandas cross merge:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( [[1,'Jane'],[2,'Max'],[3,'Tom'],[4,'Beth']], columns=["ID","NAME"] )
print(df)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        [['2022-01-01'],['2022-01-02'],['2022-01-03'],['2022-01-04']],
        columns=['DATE'])
print(df2)
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, how='cross')
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
   ID  NAME
0   1  Jane
1   2   Max
2   3   Tom
3   4  Beth
         DATE
0  2022-01-01
1  2022-01-02
2  2022-01-03
3  2022-01-04
    ID  NAME        DATE
0    1  Jane  2022-01-01
1    1  Jane  2022-01-02
2    1  Jane  2022-01-03
3    1  Jane  2022-01-04
4    2   Max  2022-01-01
5    2   Max  2022-01-02
6    2   Max  2022-01-03
7    2   Max  2022-01-04
8    3   Tom  2022-01-01
9    3   Tom  2022-01-02
10   3   Tom  2022-01-03
11   3   Tom  2022-01-04
12   4  Beth  2022-01-01
13   4  Beth  2022-01-02
14   4  Beth  2022-01-03
15   4  Beth  2022-01-04
```

Comment: You can use `pandas.date_range`: `df.merge(pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-01-04').to_series(name='Date'), how='cross')` ;)